# Can someone help me with this SQL error, essentially u1 and u2 are pulling the same value

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.MAIN_SYSTEM, 
       VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.MAIN_ROLE, 
       U1.ROLEPROFDISPNAME, 
       VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.DEPENDANT_SYSTEM, 
       VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.DEPENDANT_ROLE, 
       U2.ROLEPROFDISPNAME
    FROM VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP
        INNER JOIN VIRSA_AE_ROLDTLS U1 
            ON VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.MAIN_ROLE = U1.ROLEPROFNAME
        LEFT JOIN VIRSA_AE_ROLDTLS U2 
            ON VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.DEPENDANT_ROLE = U2.ROLEPROFNAME ;
```

Comment: Please provide DDL, sample data, expected results.  With this information we cannot help you.  DETAILS!

Answer (score 0):

the sub query inside the braces is not a valid select

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. You posted a SELECT statement above, not a SQL error. What is the error you need help with?

I can take a wild guess and say you probably put brackets in the wrong places and want:

SELECT VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.MAIN_SYSTEM, VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.MAIN_ROLE, U1.ROLEPROFDISPNAME, VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.DEPENDANT_SYSTEM, VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.DEPENDANT_ROLE, U2.ROLEPROFDISPNAME 
FROM VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP 
INNER JOIN VIRSA_AE_ROLDTLS U1 ON VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.MAIN_ROLE = U1.ROLEPROFNAME
LEFT JOIN VIRSA_AE_ROLDTLS U2 ON VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.DEPENDANT_ROLE = U2.ROLEPROFNAME

Does that help?

Comment: VIRSA_AE_ROLDTLS
ROLEPROFNAME ROLEPROFDESC ROLEPROFDISPNAME
444 444 SAP_FI_AP_CHECK_MAINTENANCE
4440 4255 SAP_ISHMED_SERVICE_MANAGEMENT
4441 4256 SAP_BC_SRV_ARL_ADMIN
VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP
MAIN_SYSTEM MAIN_ROLE DEPENDANT_SYSTEM DEPENDANT_ROLE
ERS 0 null null
ERS 1 null null
HRD 4255 null null
HRD 4255 HRD 4250
VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.Main_role and 
VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.Dependant_role contain the unique identifier for whcih the description can be located in VIRSA_AE_ROLDTLS.ROLEPROFDISPNAME. But my query is fetching descritpon for only Main_role and repeats the same for VIRSA_AE_ROLE_MAP.Dependant_role